# Does Air India provide any compensation for delayed flights?

Tags: delays, compensation, air-india

A flight I was flying on 24th December was delayed in 3 steps, initially 1 hour, then an additional 55 min followed by an additional 15 min.

The last delay occurred 5 minutes before the departure time post the 55 min delay.

Was I entitled to anything for this or not?

This was for flight AI 951 from Hyderabad to Dubai

(possibly irrelevant info follows)

When I received the notification for the 2nd delay, I asked if refreshments would be provided (to avoid buying the insanely priced airport food) and was told to wait near the gate where they will announce the refreshments. 1 hr 40 min into the delay they said they won't provide anything since the delay is less than 2 hours, and I couldn't really go and buy anything at this time since it would have been only 15 min before departure.

When the additional 15 min delay was announced, they said that there is not enough time to arrange for refreshments and hence will not be providing them.

The primary reason I ask is if I should or should not expect refreshments to appear in such situations in the future…  It wasn't pleasant being hungry for so long.

Comment: Even under the ultra-strict compensation regulations in the European Union (EU261) there would be no compensation due for a delay of less than 3 hours on a route like this.

In India, I think anything less than 24 hours late is generally considered on-time...

Comment: @Doc Interesting..  Looks like Eu is also proposing to reduce the threshold for refreshments to a blanket 2 hours as per Wikipedia..  and, your latter comment is incorrect and ignorant

Comment: If anyone knows the equivalent of EU261 for India, please do post it

Comment: Can you also post the reason for the delay? Is it weather or something that the airliner can't do anything about?

Comment: @AyeshK I do not know how true it is, but I was told it was the result of a cascade delay due to flights from Delhi at 9-10 am (my flight was at 8 30 pm) being delayed, which caused all further flights to be delayed, which caused this aircraft to reach Vizag(1st stop on this route) late, due to which our departure was delayed   Would that even be considered weather related?

Comment: In my experience, they don't even respond to messages to customer support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given your update of the question to the correct date of December 24th, 2014...

Your flight departed around 2 hours and 22 minutes late.  It has a normal scheduled flight time of just under 4 hours.

According to the regulations set by the Indian Office of the Director General Of Civil Aviation (available [here](http://dgca.nic.in/kyrdgca/pdf/Delay-Cancellation-&-Denied-Boarding/D3M-M4.pdf)) the airline is required to provide "Meals and refreshments" when the flight is delayed "3 hours or more in case of flights having a block time of more than 2 ½ hrs and up to 5 hours".

As your flight was only delayed less than 3 hours, they had no legal need to provide food or refreshments.

Further there is no mention of compensation for such a delay, and given that there wasn't a need to even provide refreshments then there would obviously be no expectation of compensation.

Answer (score 3):

According to [FlightAware](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/AIC951/history/20141225/1500ZZ/VOHS/OMDB) (free account required to view) AI951 on December 25, 2014 left Rajiv Gandhi International Airport in Hyderabad roughly on-time, and arrived in Dubai at 22:53 GST, approximately 38 minutes beyond it's scheduled arrival time of 22:15 GST.

Compensation is certainly not due for a 38 minute late arrival, regardless of what airline you are flying on.

Comment: Whoops, it was 24th, mixed it up as 25th since arrival was on 25th :)

Comment: http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?id=479318003&airlineCode=AI&flightNumber=951

Comment: You may want to update the question then...

Answer (score 0):

A few years back, I suffered a delay of 24 hours in Delhi.  I was flying on Air India from Hyderabad to Birmingham via Delhi.  My connection time was very generous (several hours) but my flight from Hyderabad was so late that I arrived just in time to see my intended next flight take off.  I was given free good (reasonable local food) and put in a hotel which was terrible.  I tried complaining after getting home.  I could not get customer services to respond let alone compensate me.